# Reject voice calls on Windows Fax?

Tags: windows-7, fax

Is there a way to reject voice calls when the line is hooked up to a fax modem on Windows Fax? Since this is a dedicated fax line, I don't want any voice calls to ring.

Comment: There is no way for anything on your end to know if the call is phone or fax until it answers the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A telephone line has no way of knowing what or whom is calling.  Your best bet is to contact your phone company and get a distinctive ring line added to your account.  They are usually very inexpensive.  The software can then detect the special ring and only answer it.  Start giving out that new phone line # as a fax only line.